# Delphi: StringList Delimiter is always a space character even if Delimiter is set

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, delimiter, tstringlist

I am having trouble with the delimiter in the TStringList Class. Take a look:

```
var
  s: string;
  sl: TStringList;

begin
  sl := TStringList.Create;
  s := 'Users^foo bar^bar foo^foobar^barfoo';
  sl.Delimiter := '^';
  sl.DelimitedText := s;
  ShowMessage(sl[1]);
end;
```

`sl[1]` SHOULD return `'foo bar'`

`sl[1]` DOES return `'foo'`

It seems that the delimiter is now `'^'` AND `' '`

Any ideas?

Comment: What version of Delphi are you working in?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Split a string into an array of strings based on a delimiter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2625707/split-a-string-into-an-array-of-strings-based-on-a-delimiter)

Comment: I've never been more angry with a language bug than I am right now. Thank you, Acron, for bringing this to my attention.

Answer (score 96, accepted):

You should set `s1.StrictDelimiter := True` for spaces not to be considered delimiters, more info [here](http://jedqc.blogspot.com/2005/12/d2006-new-strictdelimiter-property.html).

Since you work in a version that does not support the above (as was clarified after the answer was submitted), you have two options:

1. Find a character you know will not be used in the original text (e.g. underscore), convert all spaces to that character before splitting, and convert back after splitting. This is [robosoft](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3897/robsoft)'s suggestion.
2. If you don't have inverted commas and spaces in the text, you can use [Alexander](https://stackoverflow.com/users/92713/alexander)'s trick and wrap the text between delimiters in inverted command, so that `'hello hello^bye bye'` turns to `'"hello hello"^"bye bye"'`. If you do choose this path and it works for you, please accept Alexander's answer and not mine, he also provides the code to implement it.

Both workarounds not using `StrictDelimiter` have limitations: the first requires some unused character, and the second requires no inverted commas and spaces in the original text.

Maybe it's time to upgrade to a newer version of Delphi :)

Comment: What do you want to work around? Looks like a solution to me.

Comment: Your starting point would be to read the source code for SetDelimitedText in Classes.pas, and either subclass TStrings to create a version that handles this the way you need, or just write a stand-alone function to split the string on carets and return a string list.

Comment: Could you temporarily turn spaces into something else, then change them back afterwards? Any other character that wouldn't normally appear in your list would work. It's a hack, or as we prefer 'necessary evil as a workaround'. :-)

Comment: @Todd - That was the first significant sub-class I ever wrote in Delphi 3!

Answer (score 19):

```
sl.DelimitedText := '"' + StringReplace(S, sl.Delimiter, '"' + sl.Delimiter + '"', [rfReplaceAll]) + '"';
```

Comment: Crap, you beat me, I was typing exactly the same answer :)

Comment: Very clever, thank you Alexander, aswell as The_Fox, even if you diddn't help me directly, but you intended to do so :)

Comment: +1 Very nice, but has a problem if the original string contains a subsection like ' " " ' (i.e. inverted commas and spaces in the text)

Comment: >>> has a problem if the original string contains a subsection like ' " " '

And how can user name contain '"' char? :)

Comment: @Alexander - Here's an example: 'Bill "The Womanizer" Clinton' :)

Answer (score 6):

Ryan has provider an excellent solution to this problem using ExtractStrings() function in Delphi. See:

[Parsing a string using a delimiter to a TStringList, seems to also parse on spaces (Delphi)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3063930/parsing-a-string-using-a-delimiter-to-a-tstringlist-seems-to-also-parse-on-spac)

So in your case, replace calls to sl.Delimiter and sl.DelimitedText with the line below:
**ExtractStrings(['^'], [], PChar(S), sl);**

Answer (score 4):

Work's in Delphi 7 "like gloves" for me. This is my function after apply Alexander's Trick:

```
procedure Split (const Delimiter: Char; Input: string; const Strings: TStrings) ;
begin
   Assert(Assigned(Strings)) ;
   Strings.Clear;
   Strings.Delimiter := Delimiter;
   Strings.DelimitedText :=  '"' + StringReplace(Input, Delimiter, '"' + Delimiter + '"', [rfReplaceAll]) + '"' ;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Edit1.Text := 'Users^foo bar^bar foo^foobar^barfoo';
  Split('^',Edit1.Text,Memo1.Lines);
end;
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

```
sl.Text := StringReplace(S, sl.Delimiter, sLineBreak, [rfReplaceAll]);
```

Comment: You should probably add an explanation on what this is doing.

Answer (score 0):

```
var
  MyString: String;
  Splitted: TArray<String>;

begin
  MyString := String.Join(',', ['String1', 'String2', 'String3']);
  Splitted := MyString.Split([','], 2);
end.
```

options:

Count : Maximum number of splits to return; defaults to MaxInt if not specified.

QuoteStart/QuoteEnd : Start and end characters of a quoted part of the string where the separator is ignored.

Options : Controls if any empty matches, or if trailing empty matches are included.

[More info](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Alexandria/en/System.SysUtils.TStringHelper.Split)