# Split a string into an array of strings based on a delimiter

Tags: delphi, string, split, delimiter

I'm trying to find a Delphi function that will split an input string into an array of strings based on a delimiter. I've found a lot from searching the web, but all seem to have their own issues and I haven't been able to get any of them to work.

I just need to split a string like:
`"word:doc,txt,docx"` into an array based on ':'. The result would be
`['word', 'doc,txt,docx']`. How can I do that?

Answer (score 102, accepted):

you can use the TStrings.DelimitedText property for split an string

check this sample

```
program Project28;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  Classes,
  SysUtils;

procedure Split(Delimiter: Char; Str: string; ListOfStrings: TStrings) ;
begin
   ListOfStrings.Clear;
   ListOfStrings.Delimiter       := Delimiter;
   ListOfStrings.StrictDelimiter := True; // Requires D2006 or newer.
   ListOfStrings.DelimitedText   := Str;
end;


var
   OutPutList: TStringList;
begin
   OutPutList := TStringList.Create;
   try
     Split(':', 'word:doc,txt,docx', OutPutList) ;
     Writeln(OutPutList.Text);
     Readln;
   finally
     OutPutList.Free;
   end;
end.
```

UPDATE

See this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1335027/delphi-stringlist-delimiter-is-always-a-space-character-even-if-delimiter-is-set) for an explanation of `StrictDelimiter`.

Comment: Unfortunately there is a bug in many "older" Delphi versions (not sure with which release this got fixed) which has the effect that the space character is **always** used as delimiter. So handle this with care!!

Comment: Yeah.  You'll want to set StrictDelimiter to true, and if the StrictDelimiter property is not available in your version of Delphi, don't use this technique!  But if it is, then this is very useful.

Comment: It wasn't a bug, it was an (annoying) design decision way back in D1 or D2. CommaText was supposed to enclose any fields with spaces with quotes. If the input has double quotes around any fields with spaces, the result is correct.

Comment: One of my pet peeves is when people needlessly put type indicators in variable/parameter names.  Pascal is strongly typed - it's redundant typing (of the finger exercise variety) and confusingly misleading when the type indicator is wrong, as in this case:  ArrayOfStrings *isn't* an array (and as such doesn't even answer the question as posed).

Comment: @Deltics, you are right the name chosen for the variable is very bad, I've changed. thanks for your observation.

Comment: For everyone upvoting this answer, please note that it doesn't yield an array, as specified in the question.  Incomplete requirements specification is a big problem in this industry, ignoring stated requirements and delivering something not asked for is another big problem.  Approving of either simply encourages bad practice.  ;)

Comment: That's a list, not an "array".

Comment: Using D7, setting `Delimiter` to other than the space default seems to work, **as long as the space char does not exists** in the string. Meaning that `aStringList.Delimiter:='@'; aStringList.DelimitedText:='One@Two@Three'` works fine, while `aStringList.DelimitedText:='One time@Two times@Three times'` does not work as expected. So **replacing spaces** with (lets say) underscores before assigning the `.DelimitedText` would do the work.

Answer (score 80):

There is no need for engineering a `Split` function. It already exists, see: [`Classes.ExtractStrings`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/Classes.ExtractStrings).

Use it in a following manner:

```
program Project1;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  Classes;

var
  List: TStrings;
begin
  List := TStringList.Create;
  try
    ExtractStrings([':'], [], PChar('word:doc,txt,docx'), List);
    WriteLn(List.Text);
    ReadLn;
  finally
    List.Free;
  end;
end.
```

And to answer the question fully; `List` represents the desired array with the elements:

```
List[0] = 'word'
List[1] = 'doc,txt,docx'
```

Comment: ExtractStrings is very inflexible: "Carriage returns, newline characters, and quote characters (single or double) are always treated as separators."; and "Note:  ExtractStrings does not add empty strings to the list."

Comment: The problem is not to engineer a `split` function, but the need of a `TStrings` object. And because of the inflexibility (@awmross) mentions, I'd prefer [Frank's solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2628241/2932052)

Comment: Also `ExtractStrings` cannot split on a string - only a `Char` (or some `set of Char`)

Answer (score 59):

You can use [`StrUtils.SplitString`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.StrUtils.SplitString).

```
function SplitString(const S, Delimiters: string): TStringDynArray;
```

Its description from the [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.StrUtils.SplitString):

> Splits a string into different parts delimited by the specified
>   delimiter characters.
>
> **SplitString** splits a string into different parts delimited by the specified delimiter characters. **S** is the string to be split.
>   **Delimiters** is a string containing the characters defined as delimiters.
>
> **SplitString** returns an array of strings of type [System.Types.TStringDynArray](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Types.TStringDynArray) that contains the split parts of the
>   original string.

Comment: Hmmm, not in my version of Delphi 2010 (there is a SplitString routine in XMLDoc and in (Indy unit) IdStrings, but neither of these do what the poster wants and the XMLDoc routine isn't exposed through the unit interface anyway).

Comment: function SplitString(const S, Delimiters: string): TStringDynArray; defined in StrUtils.pas

Comment: I am not able to include file StrUtils.pas (even when present).

Comment: This IS an example of splitting a string into an "array".

Comment: best thing is that this accepts a string delimiter as opposed to char delimiters in other answers.

Comment: Don't know when it was added. Certainly not in Delphi 5. Deltics says also wasn't around in 2010.

Answer (score 55):

Using the [SysUtils.TStringHelper.Split](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SysUtils.TStringHelper.Split) function, introduced in Delphi XE3:

```
var
  MyString: String;
  Splitted: TArray<String>;
begin
  MyString := 'word:doc,txt,docx';
  Splitted := MyString.Split([':']);
end.
```

This will split a string with a given delimiter into an array of strings.

Answer (score 22):

I always use something similar to this:

```
Uses
   StrUtils, Classes;

Var
  Str, Delimiter : String;
begin
  // Str is the input string, Delimiter is the delimiter
  With TStringList.Create Do
  try
    Text := ReplaceText(S,Delim,#13#10);

    // From here on and until "finally", your desired result strings are
    // in strings[0].. strings[Count-1)

  finally
    Free; //Clean everything up, and liberate your memory ;-)
  end;

end;
```

Comment: Great solution for users of older Delphi versions.

Comment: C++ Builder 6 users: the corresponding function is `Strutils::AnsiReplaceText`

Comment: Amazingly simple. Working in Delphi 7 with: `list.Text := AnsiReplaceStr(source, delimiter, #13#10);`.

Comment: In Delphi 6 can use SysUtils.StringReplace

Comment: Sweet little solution for Delphi 6. BTW, ReplaceText (case-insensitive) should be StringReplace (case-sensitive) or AnsiReplaceStr (which simply calls StringReplace) which @AlainD already mentioned.

Comment: Sorry to say, there is an issue with this code that new lines will be split even if your delimiter is something else (unfortunately that's what assigning to .Text has always done). An ugly interim step would be to replace existing lines to something else first (and back again after split). I wrote a simple parser instead, see my answer.

Comment: Fails when your text already contains `CRLF`

Answer (score 17):

Similar to the **Explode()** function offered by Mef, but with a couple of differences (one of which I consider a bug fix):

```
  type
    TArrayOfString = array of String;


  function SplitString(const aSeparator, aString: String; aMax: Integer = 0): TArrayOfString;
  var
    i, strt, cnt: Integer;
    sepLen: Integer;

    procedure AddString(aEnd: Integer = -1);
    var
      endPos: Integer;
    begin
      if (aEnd = -1) then
        endPos := i
      else
        endPos := aEnd + 1;

      if (strt < endPos) then
        result[cnt] := Copy(aString, strt, endPos - strt)
      else
        result[cnt] := '';

      Inc(cnt);
    end;

  begin
    if (aString = '') or (aMax < 0) then
    begin
      SetLength(result, 0);
      EXIT;
    end;

    if (aSeparator = '') then
    begin
      SetLength(result, 1);
      result[0] := aString;
      EXIT;
    end;

    sepLen := Length(aSeparator);
    SetLength(result, (Length(aString) div sepLen) + 1);

    i     := 1;
    strt  := i;
    cnt   := 0;
    while (i <= (Length(aString)- sepLen + 1)) do
    begin
      if (aString[i] = aSeparator[1]) then
        if (Copy(aString, i, sepLen) = aSeparator) then
        begin
          AddString;

          if (cnt = aMax) then
          begin
            SetLength(result, cnt);
            EXIT;
          end;

          Inc(i, sepLen - 1);
          strt := i + 1;
        end;

      Inc(i);
    end;

    AddString(Length(aString));

    SetLength(result, cnt);
  end;
```

Differences:

1. aMax parameter limits the number of strings to be returned
2. If the input string is terminated by a separator then a nominal "empty" final string is deemed to exist

Examples:

```
SplitString(':', 'abc') returns      :    result[0]  = abc

SplitString(':', 'a:b:c:') returns   :    result[0]  = a
                                          result[1]  = b
                                          result[2]  = c
                                          result[3]  = <empty string>

SplitString(':', 'a:b:c:', 2) returns:    result[0]  = a
                                          result[1]  = b
```

It is the trailing separator and notional "empty final element" that I consider the bug fix.

I also incorporated the memory allocation change I suggested, with refinement (I mistakenly suggested the input string might at most contain 50% separators, but it could conceivably of course consist of 100% separator strings, yielding an array of empty elements!)

Answer (score 7):

Explode is very high speed function, source alhoritm get from TStrings component.
I use next test for explode:
Explode 134217733 bytes of data, i get 19173962 elements, time of work: 2984 ms.

Implode is very low speed function, but i write it easy.

```
{ ****************************************************************************** }
{  Explode/Implode (String <> String array)                                      }
{ ****************************************************************************** }
function Explode(S: String; Delimiter: Char): Strings; overload;
var I, C: Integer; P, P1: PChar;
begin
    SetLength(Result, 0);
    if Length(S) = 0 then Exit;
    P:=PChar(S+Delimiter); C:=0;
    while P^ <> #0 do begin
       P1:=P;
       while (P^ <> Delimiter) do P:=CharNext(P);
       Inc(C);
       while P^ in [#1..' '] do P:=CharNext(P);
       if P^ = Delimiter then begin
          repeat
           P:=CharNext(P);
          until not (P^ in [#1..' ']);
       end;
    end;
    SetLength(Result, C);
    P:=PChar(S+Delimiter); I:=-1;
    while P^ <> #0 do begin
       P1:=P;
       while (P^ <> Delimiter) do P:=CharNext(P);
       Inc(I); SetString(Result[I], P1, P-P1);
       while P^ in [#1..' '] do P:=CharNext(P);
       if P^ = Delimiter then begin
          repeat
           P:=CharNext(P);
          until not (P^ in [#1..' ']);
       end;
    end;
end;

function Explode(S: String; Delimiter: Char; Index: Integer): String; overload;
var I: Integer; P, P1: PChar;
begin
    if Length(S) = 0 then Exit;
    P:=PChar(S+Delimiter); I:=1;
    while P^ <> #0 do begin
       P1:=P;
       while (P^ <> Delimiter) do P:=CharNext(P);
        SetString(Result, P1, P-P1);
        if (I <> Index) then Inc(I) else begin
           SetString(Result, P1, P-P1); Exit;
        end;
       while P^ in [#1..' '] do P:=CharNext(P);
       if P^ = Delimiter then begin
          repeat
           P:=CharNext(P);
          until not (P^ in [#1..' ']);
       end;
    end;
end;

function Implode(S: Strings; Delimiter: Char): String;
var iCount: Integer;
begin
     Result:='';
     if (Length(S) = 0) then Exit;
     for iCount:=0 to Length(S)-1 do
     Result:=Result+S[iCount]+Delimiter;
     System.Delete(Result, Length(Result), 1);
end;
```

Comment: This does not compile: `Strings` is not a type.

Answer (score 7):

```
var  
    su  : string;        // What we want split
    si  : TStringList;   // Result of splitting
    Delimiter : string;
    ...
    Delimiter := ';';
    si.Text := ReplaceStr(su, Delimiter, #13#10);
```

Lines in **si** list will contain splitted strings.

Answer (score 6):

You can make your own function which returns TArray of string:

```
function mySplit(input: string): TArray<string>;
var
  delimiterSet: array [0 .. 0] of char; 
     // split works with char array, not a single char
begin
  delimiterSet[0] := '&'; // some character
  result := input.Split(delimiterSet);
end;
```

Answer (score 5):

[Here](http://www.delphipraxis.net/topic3816_ein+dynamisches+array+aus+einem+string+erzeugen.html) is an implementation of an explode function which is available in many other programming languages as a standard function:

```
type 
  TStringDynArray = array of String;

function Explode(const Separator, S: string; Limit: Integer = 0): TStringDynArray; 
var 
  SepLen: Integer; 
  F, P: PChar; 
  ALen, Index: Integer; 
begin 
  SetLength(Result, 0); 
  if (S = '') or (Limit < 0) then Exit; 
  if Separator = '' then 
  begin 
    SetLength(Result, 1); 
    Result[0] := S; 
    Exit; 
  end; 
  SepLen := Length(Separator); 
  ALen := Limit; 
  SetLength(Result, ALen); 

  Index := 0; 
  P := PChar(S); 
  while P^ <> #0 do 
  begin 
    F := P; 
    P := AnsiStrPos(P, PChar(Separator)); 
    if (P = nil) or ((Limit > 0) and (Index = Limit - 1)) then P := StrEnd(F); 
    if Index >= ALen then 
    begin 
      Inc(ALen, 5); 
      SetLength(Result, ALen); 
    end; 
    SetString(Result[Index], F, P - F); 
    Inc(Index); 
    if P^ <> #0 then Inc(P, SepLen); 
  end; 
  if Index < ALen then SetLength(Result, Index); 
end;
```

Sample usage:

```
var
  res: TStringDynArray;
begin
  res := Explode(':', yourString);
```

Comment: There are some strange and potentially hugely inefficient choices in this code for managing/anticipating the length of result.  By growing the result array incrementally, the chances of memory re-allocations and fragmentation are increased.  More efficient would be to set an initial length as large as it might possibly be i.e. assume that the input string consists of 50% separator strings = Length(S) div (2 * Length(Separator).  Then set it to the actual number of items when done.  1 allocation followed potentially by a single truncation.

Comment: Also you don't explain the purpose of the Limit parameter.  I intuitively expected it to set a maximum number of substrings to be returned when in fact it appears to constrain the detection of substrings to the first "Limit" # of characters in the input string.  This seems pointless since if you needed to do that you could simply operate Explode() over a Copy() of the required substring.  Using Limit to set a maximum number of substrings would be far more useful.

Comment: @Deltics: Nobody claimed that this is a highly optimized function, and nobody asked for one, so I somewhat don't understand your complaint. But maybe you are one of the guys who optimize everything, regardless if it is necessary or not...

Comment: I'm the kind of guy that doesn't write needlessly inefficient code then worry about optimising later.  This wasn't a case of analysing the code minutely and finding some miniscule optimisation potential, it was simply an obvious and easily addressed inefficiency:  Incremental growth of contiguous memory that can instead easily be pre-allocated and subsequently truncated.

Comment: Also @Mef: And it wasn't a complaint, it was a comment, an observation.  But more importantly your code also contained what I would consider a bug (see my alternative for an explanation).

Answer (score 5):

I wrote this function which returns linked list of separated strings by specific delimiter. Pure free pascal without modules.

```
Program split_f;

type
    PTItem = ^TItem;
    TItem = record
        str : string;
        next : PTItem;
    end;

var
    s : string;
    strs : PTItem;

procedure split(str : string;delim : char;var list : PTItem);
var
    i : integer;
    buff : PTItem;
begin
    new(list);
    buff:= list;
    buff^.str:='';
    buff^.next:=nil;

    for i:=1 to length(str) do begin
        if (str[i] = delim) then begin
            new(buff^.next);
            buff:=buff^.next;
            buff^.str := '';
            buff^.next := nil;
        end
        else
        buff^.str:= buff^.str+str[i];
    end;
end;

procedure print(var list:PTItem);
var
    buff : PTItem;
begin
    buff := list;
    while buff<>nil do begin
        writeln(buff^.str);
        buff:= buff^.next;
    end;
end;

begin

    s := 'Hi;how;are;you?';

    split(s, ';', strs);
    print(strs);


end.
```

Answer (score 3):

Jedi Code Library provides an enhanced StringList with built-in Split function, that is capable of both adding and replacing the existing text. It also provides reference-counted interface. So this can be used even with older Delphi versions that have no SplitStrings and without careful and a bit tedious customizations of stock TStringList to only use specified delimiters.

For example given text file of lines like `Dog 5 4 7` one can parse them using:

```
var slF, slR: IJclStringList; ai: TList<integer>; s: string; i: integer;
    action: procedure(const Name: string; Const Data: array of integer);

slF := TJclStringList.Create; slF.LoadFromFile('some.txt');
slR := TJclStringList.Create;
for s in slF do begin
    slR.Split(s, ' ', true);
    ai := TList<Integer>.Create;
    try
       for i := 1 to slR.Count - 1 do
           ai.Add(StrToInt(slR[i]));
       action(slR[0], ai.ToArray);
    finally ai.Free; end;
end;
```

http://wiki.delphi-jedi.org/wiki/JCL_Help:IJclStringList.Split@string@string@Boolean

Answer (score 3):

This will solve your problem

```
interface
   TArrayStr = Array Of string;

implementation

function SplitString(Text: String): TArrayStr;
var
   intIdx: Integer;
   intIdxOutput: Integer;
const
   Delimiter = ';';
begin
   intIdxOutput := 0;
   SetLength(Result, 1);
   Result[0] := ''; 

   for intIdx := 1 to Length(Text) do
   begin
      if Text[intIdx] = Delimiter then
      begin
         intIdxOutput := intIdxOutput + 1;
         SetLength(Result, Length(Result) + 1);
      end
      else
         Result[intIdxOutput] := Result[intIdxOutput] + Text[intIdx];
   end;
end;
```

Comment: Can you please give some explanation on what the code does? Thanks

Comment: it runs through the passed string looking for the delimiter const, when not found, concatenate with the current position on the array, when founds, its jumps to next position in the dynamic array

Answer (score 1):

My favourite function for splitting:

```
procedure splitString(delim: char; s: string; ListOfStrings: TStrings);
var temp: string;
    i: integer;
begin
   ListOfStrings.Clear;
   for i:=1 to length(s) do
    begin
      if s[i] = delim then
        begin
          ListOfStrings.add(temp);
          temp := '';
        end
      else
        begin
          temp := temp + s[i];
          if i=length(s) then
             ListOfStrings.add(temp);
        end;
    end;
    ListOfStrings.add(temp);
end;
```

Comment: The last element was missed in your function

Comment: You need to add `ListOfStrings.add(temp);` after the loop to add last item.

Comment: Thanks for the note, I edited the code in else block.

Answer (score 0):

*

```
//Basic functionality of a TStringList solves this:


uses Classes  //TStringList 
    ,types    //TStringDynArray
    ,SysUtils //StringReplace()
    ;

....

 //--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 function _SplitString(const s:string; const delimiter:Char):TStringDynArray;
  var sl:TStringList;
      i:integer;
  begin
  sl:=TStringList.Create;

  //separete delimited items by sLineBreak;TStringlist will do the job:
  sl.Text:=StringReplace(s,delimiter,sLineBreak,[rfReplaceAll]);

  //return the splitted string as an array:
  setlength(Result,sl.count);
  for i:=0 to sl.Count-1
   do Result[i]:=sl[i];

  sl.Free;
  end;



//To split a FileName (last item will be the pure filename itselfs):

 function _SplitPath(const fn:TFileName):TStringDynArray;
  begin
  result:=_SplitString(fn,'\');
  end;
```

*

Answer (score 0):

The base of NGLG answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/8811242/6619626 you can use the following function:

```
type
OurArrayStr=array of string;

function SplitString(DelimeterChars:char;Str:string):OurArrayStr;
var
seg: TStringList;
i:integer;
ret:OurArrayStr;
begin
    seg := TStringList.Create;
    ExtractStrings([DelimeterChars],[], PChar(Str), seg);
    for i:=0 to seg.Count-1 do
    begin
         SetLength(ret,length(ret)+1);
         ret[length(ret)-1]:=seg.Strings[i];
    end;
    SplitString:=ret;
    seg.Free;
end;
```

It works in all Delphi versions.

Answer (score 0):

For delphi 2010, you need to create your own split function.

```
function Split(const Texto, Delimitador: string): TStringArray;
var
  i: integer;
  Len: integer;
  PosStart: integer;
  PosDel: integer;
  TempText:string;
begin
  i := 0;
  SetLength(Result, 1);
  Len := Length(Delimitador);
  PosStart := 1;
  PosDel := Pos(Delimitador, Texto);
  TempText:=  Texto;
  while PosDel > 0 do
    begin
      Result[i] := Copy(TempText, PosStart, PosDel - PosStart);
      PosStart := PosDel + Len;
      TempText:=Copy(TempText, PosStart, Length(TempText));
      PosDel := Pos(Delimitador, TempText);
      PosStart := 1;
      inc(i);
      SetLength(Result, i + 1);
    end;
  Result[i] := Copy(TempText, PosStart, Length(TempText));
end;
```

You can refer to it as such

```
type
  TStringArray = array of string;
var Temp2:TStringArray;
Temp1="hello:world";
Temp2=Split(Temp1,':')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
procedure SplitCSV(S:STRING;out SL:TStringList);
var c,commatext:string;
  a,b,up:integer;
begin
   c:=s.Replace(' ','<SPACE>');   //curate spaces

   //first ocurrence of "
   a:=pos('"',c);
   b:=pos('"',c,a+1);
   if (a>0) and (b>0) then
   begin
     commatext:=commatext+copy(c,0,a-1);
     commatext:=commatext+copy(c,a,b-a+1).Replace(',','<COMMA>');   //curate commas
     up:=b+1;
   end
   else
     commatext:=c;

   //while continue discovering "
   while (a>0) and (b>0) do
   begin
     a:=Pos('"',c,b+1);
     b:=pos('"',c,a+1);
     if (a>0) and (b>0) then
     begin
       commatext:=commatext+copy(c,up,a-up);
       commatext:=commatext+copy(c,a,b-a+1).Replace(',','<COMMA>'); //curate commas
       up:=b+1;
     end;
   end;
   //last piece of text end  
   if up<c.Length then
     commatext:=commatext+copy(c,up,c.Length-up+1);

   //split text using CommaText
   sl.CommaText:=commatext;

   sl.Text:=sl.Text.Replace('<COMMA>',',');   //curate commas
   sl.Text:=sl.Text.Replace('<SPACE>',' ');   //curate spaces
end;
```

Comment: Answers which explain the solution clearly and succintly are much more useful than code-only ones.

Answer (score 0):

```
interface

uses
  Classes;

type
  TStringArray = array of string;

  TUtilStr = class
    class function Split(const AValue: string; const ADelimiter: Char = ';'; const AQuoteChar: Char = '"'): TStringArray; static;
  end;


implementation

{ TUtilStr }

class function TUtilStr.Split(const AValue: string; const ADelimiter: Char; const AQuoteChar: Char): TStringArray;
var
  LSplited: TStringList;
  LText: string;
  LIndex: Integer;
begin
  LSplited := TStringList.Create;
  try
    LSplited.StrictDelimiter := True;
    LSplited.Delimiter := ADelimiter;
    LSplited.QuoteChar := AQuoteChar;
    LSplited.DelimitedText := AValue;

    SetLength(Result, LSplited.Count);
    for LIndex := 0 to LSplited.Count - 1 do
    begin
      Result[LIndex] := LSplited[LIndex];
    end;
  finally
    LSplited.Free;
  end;
end;

end.
```

Answer (score 0):

I initially praised the answer from @Frank as I needed something that works for Delphi 6 and it appeared to work. However, I have since found that that solution has a bug whereby it still splits on #13#10 regardless of delimiter. Works perfectly if you are not expecting lines in your source string.

I wrote a simple parser that only works for single character delimiters. Note: it puts the values into a TStrings, not into an array as the op requested, but can easily be modified to adapt to arrays.

Here is the procedure:

```
procedure SplitString(const ASource: string; const ADelimiter: Char; AValues: TStrings);
var
  i, lastDelimPos: Integer;
begin
  AValues.Clear;
  lastDelimPos := 0;

  for i := 1 to Length(ASource) do
    if ASource[i] = ADelimiter then
    begin
      if lastDelimPos = 0 then
        AValues.Add(CopyRange(ASource, 1, i - 1))
      else
        AValues.Add(CopyRange(ASource, lastDelimPos + 1, i - 1));
      lastDelimPos := i;
    end;

  if lastDelimPos = 0 then
    AValues.Add(ASource)
  else
    AValues.Add(CopyRange(ASource, lastDelimPos + 1, MaxInt));
end;

function CopyRange(const s: string; const AIndexFrom, AIndexTo: Integer): string;
begin
  Result := Copy(s, AIndexFrom, AIndexTo - AIndexFrom + 1);
end;
```

Note: as per C#'s string.Split(), a blank input string will result in a single blank string in the TStrings. Similarly, just having a delimiter by itself as the input string would result in two blank strings in the TStrings.

Here is the rough test code I used to ensure it's solid:

```
procedure AddTest(const ATestLine: string; const AExpectedResult: array of string);
var
  expectedResult: TStringList;
  i: Integer;
begin
  expectedResult := TStringList.Create;
  for i := 0 to Length(AExpectedResult) - 1 do
    expectedResult.Add(AExpectedResult[i]);
  testStrings.AddObject(ATestLine, expectedResult);
end;

//====================

AddTest('test', ['test']);
AddTest('', ['']);
AddTest(',', ['', '']);
AddTest('line1' + #13#10 + ',line 2,line3, line 4', ['line1' + #13#10, 'line 2', 'line3', ' line 4']);
AddTest('line1' + #13#10 + 'd,line 2,line3, line 4', ['line1' + #13#10 + 'd', 'line 2', 'line3', ' line 4']);
AddTest('line1,line 2,line3, line 4', ['line1', 'line 2', 'line3', ' line 4']);
AddTest('test, ', ['test', ' ']);
AddTest('test,', ['test', '']);
AddTest('test1,test2 ', ['test1', 'test2 ']);
AddTest('test1,test2', ['test1', 'test2']);
AddTest('test1,test2, ', ['test1', 'test2', ' ']);
AddTest('test1,test2,', ['test1', 'test2', '']);

//====================

testFailed := False;
for i := 0 to testStrings.Count - 1 do
begin
  SplitString2(testStrings[i], ',', f);
  log('Test ID=%d', [i]);
  log('    Test String="%s"', [testStrings[i]]);
  log('    Item count=%d', [f.Count]);
  testResult := TStringList(TestStrings.Objects[i]);
  if testResult.Count <> f.Count then
  begin
    Log('!!');
    Log('!! Count mismatch. Got=%d, Expected=%d', [f.Count, testResult.Count]);
    Log('!!');

    testFailed := True;
  end;

  for j := 0 to f.Count - 1 do
  begin
    log('    Item %d="%s"    (len=%d)', [j, f[j], Length(f[j])]);
    if testResult[j] <> f[j] then
    begin
      Log('!!');
      Log('!! Text mismatch. Got="%s", Expected="%s"', [f[j], testResult[j]]);
      Log('!!');

      testFailed := True;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Edit: code for the CopyRange() function was missing, added now. My bad.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post but here is my take on the question. As someone who deals regularly with a lot of delimited files I find this useful:

```
interface

type
  TStringArray = array[0..8] of string; // for my purposes

implementation

function aParse(aString : string):TStringArray;
var
  I, Count : Integer;
  IArray : TStringArray;
begin
  Count := 0;
  aString := aString + ','; // there are no trailing commas in my lines
  I := 0;
  repeat
    if aString[I] = ',' then
      begin
        if (I = 1) then
          begin
            IArray[Count] :='';
            Delete(aString,1,1);
            Inc(Count);
            I := 0;
          end
        else
          begin
            IArray[Count] := Copy(aString,1,I-1);
            Delete(aString,1,I);
            Inc(Count);
            I := 0;
          end;
      end;
    inc(I);
  until Count = 9;
  Result := IArray;
end;
```

My code may not be pretty (I know strings are 1 based in Windows but a lot of my lines start with ",,") but it works and will parse 100,000 lines in 0.207 seconds