# Delphi - Extract multiple substrings from a string

Tags: delphi-2010

I have a string like this

```
";;;Caption=C:;FreeSpace=103571001344;Size=162527178752;;;Caption=D:;FreeSpace=129889742848;Size=336805752832;;;Caption=V:;FreeSpace=516807241728;Size=1000207282176;;;;
```

How can I extract each partition data into a variable so that I obtain something like this:

```
partition_1:='Caption=C:;FreeSpace=103571001344;Size=162527178752';
partition_2:='Caption=D:;FreeSpace=129889742848;Size=336805752832';
partition_n:='Caption=V:;FreeSpace=516807241728;Size=1000207282176';
```

Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to split string by a multi-character delimiter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15424293/how-to-split-string-by-a-multi-character-delimiter)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15424293/how-to-split-string-by-a-multi-character-delimiter) applies to you as well. Basically, use `TStringList`, set `LineBreak` property to 3 semicolons (`;;;`) and `Text` property to your string.

Comment: When we encounter duplicate questions, rather than posting an answer linking to the duplicate, the preferred approach is to vote to close as a duplicate

Comment: Thank you! This is the correct solution! Sory for creating a duplicate question!