# Parsing Text with StringList: \n vs #13#10 vs sLineBreak

Tags: delphi, tstringlist

I'm trying to parse a string with a `TStringList`:

```
  sl:=TStringList.Create;
  try
    sl.Text:=aString;
    FFirstRow:=sl[0];
    FSecondRow:=sl[1];
  finally
    sl.Free;
  end;
```

If `aString:='aa'+#13#10+'bb'` or `aString:='aa'+sLineBreak+'bb'` then `FFirstRow` is `aa` and `FSecondRow` is `bb`. But if `aString:='aa\nbb'`then `FFirstRow` gets the whole string (and there is no second row). How do I parse the string with `\n` as a delimiter?

I tried `sl.Delimiter:=Char(13)` (and `sl.DelimitedText:=aString`).

Comment: Since `.Delimiter` is one character and not a String (`\n` are two characters) you can't. But what keeps you from replacing all `\n` occurrances with `#13#10` before?

Comment: This question is similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15424293/how-to-split-string-by-a-multi-character-delimiter/15427587#15427587 with the same valid answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just change the string that is treated as the line break in a `TStringList`:

```
  sl := TStringList.Create;
  try
    sl.LineBreak := '\n';
    sl.Text := aString;
    FFirstRow := sl[0];
    FSecondRow := sl[1];
  finally
    sl.Free;
  end;
```

Comment: Clever, yet simple. I never would have thought of that (or searched SO in a way that would have brought up your previous answer).

Answer (score 4):

The 2-character sequence `'\'`+`'n'` is not treated as an escape sequence in Delphi (only in C/C++, and only in compile-time literals, not in runtime data).  You will have to replace the sequence manually, such as with `StringReplace()`, eg:

```
aString := 'aa\nbb';
sl := TStringList.Create;
try
  sl.Text := StringReplace(aString, '\n', #10, [rfReplaceAll]);
  FFirstRow := sl[0];
  FSecondRow := sl[1];
finally
  sl.Free;
end;
```

Comment: Thanks, Remy. That works! (I think the flag is rfReplaceAll, at least in Delphi 10.3.)

Comment: @AlC yes, it is. That was just a typo, I have fixed it.