# Delphi Tell me how to DIUnicode read the rows user define for example start with rows 8?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe3

Tell me how to DIUnicode read the rows user define for example start with rows 8?
For example I start with rows 8 until 11
this one payment ..etc

```
===========================================
|Period 01.01.2012  31.12.2012
Saldo  01.01.2012            
----------------------------------------------------------------
|   Date        | Correspondet: Bank/account/Tax Name                     | 
| Payment       | Remark                                                  |   
----------------------------------------------------------------          |
|04.01.2012     | Bank:00883  account:200004000000005936111  tax:000000000|
|               |paynet                                                   |
|               |00644blbalbalbalbalbalbalbalN-4774                       |
|               |  24.03.2010                                             |
----------------------------------------------------------------
|06.01.2012     |BANK:00883  account:200004000600005000111  tax:000000000 |
|               |paynet                                                   |
|               |00644blablbalbalbalbalbalblab-4774                       |
|               |  24.03.2010 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Read line by line while counting them. Start your work, if your counter is greater than 7?

Comment: What have you tried? Show some code. We can't tell whether you are an expert Delphi programmer or a total novice. Perhaps you don't know how to create an object. We can't tell. Which Delphi version?

Comment: I'd use `TStringList.LoadFromFile`, then read lines `7,8,9,... Pred(.Count)`

Modern Delphi versions have SL able to read unicode files, for deprecated versions there are 3rd party stringlists unicode-capable.

Comment: OK Delphi version Xe3 
and i will be try 
Can you share code.. I will be try how read for example
for i=0 to stringlist.count-8 do 
begin
  data = copy(stringlist[i],2,10)
  bank = copy(stringlist[i],16,5)  
how read other rows example
2,3,4  because 4 rows one document
insert into table ()
end

Comment: Delphi version should go as tag. Now, what do u mean by "to DIUnicode"? why do you want to use Delphi Inspirations lib for starters ? And why did you mentioned Unicode while your text seems regular central-european ?

Comment: Why are you using DIUnicode? Do you need an encoding that Delphi does not support out of the box?

Comment: @David test is most probably windows-1251 http://www.sql.ru/forum/actualthread.aspx?tid=1011211 However with TStringLsit of XEx AFAIR can auto-detect UTF-8

Answer (score 0):

With the given sample the most easy thing is to use stirnglizst and iterate every line but initial 7 lines.

*I also don't know why u told about `diUnicode` library. But i assume that your file is encoded in UTF8. If it actually uses another flavour of Unicode or non-Unicode at all, then change the code accordingly.*

```
var sl: TStrings; s: String; i: integer;
begin
    sl := TStringList.Create;
    try
       sl.LoadFromFile('c:\Table.txt', TEncoding.UTF8);
       for i := 0 to 7 do sl.Delete(0); 

       for s in sl do begin
            // do some work with s 
           ShowMessage(Copy(s,18, Length(s)));
       end;
    finally
      sl.Free;
    end;
end;
```

---

You may also try to make internal parsing of string, using two advanced stringlists, like in [Split a string into an array of strings based on a delimiter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2625707/split-a-string-into-an-array-of-strings-based-on-a-delimiter#answer-14454831)

```
var slF, slR: IJclStringList; l, s: string; 

slF := TJclStringList.Create; slF.LoadFromFile('table.txt');
slR := TJclStringList.Create;

slF.Delete(0).Delete(0).Delete(0).Delete(0).Delete(0).Delete(0).Delete(0); // delete top 7 lines

for l in slF do begin
    if StartsStr('-----', l) then continue; // skip separator

    slR.Split(l, '|', true).Trim;

    for s in slR do {nothing or something} Application.Title := s ;
    ShowMessage('Date or void: '+ slR[0]);
    ShowMessage('Transfer details: '+ slR[1]);
end; 
slF := nil; slR := nil;
```