# Search numbers in different Memos and separate them into one

Tags: delphi

I'm having trouble searching for strings in different memos and separating them.
Let's go to the scene.

in Memo1 i have the following text

```
18049,25047,text4
18047,25046,text2
18048,25045,text3
18050,25048,text5
18046,25044,text1
```

and in Memo2

```
25049,9012646205,55315135004,adou4
25047,"",06252782912,textasidh
25046,"",44425660030,textblabla
25048,"",07649186806,textaldj
```

I need to separate the first digits up to the comma of memo2 and fetch into memo1 and add the complete lines. Memo1 + Memo2 in Memo3.

```
18046,25044,text1 25046,"",44425660030,textblabla
18047,25046,text2 25047,"",06252782912,textasidh
18048,25045,text3 25048,"",07649186806,textaldj
18049,25047,text4 25049,9012646205,55315135004,adou4
```

I've already tried using the `function Split(Text, Delimitador: string): TSarray;` but without success

```
var
   I, J: Byte;
   Z : String;
begin
  for I := 1 to 2 do
  begin
    for J := 0 to TMemo(FindComponent('Memo'+IntToStr(I))).Lines.Count -1 do
      begin
        Z := Memo2.Lines[J];
        if Pos(Split(Z, ',')[0],TMemo(FindComponent('Memo'+IntToStr(I))).Lines[J]) > 0 then
        Memo3.Lines.Add(TMemo(FindComponent('Memo'+IntToStr(I))).Lines[J]);
      end;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Have you looked at this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2625707/split-a-string-into-an-array-of-strings-based-on-a-delimiter

Comment: Also, you should always post some code that demonstrates where you've failed so that others can help you fix your code or your thinking.

Comment: Why are you using a memo? Use a non GUI component.

Comment: Hi @DavidHeffernan, No need to use gui interface, I'm just using it to "facilitate" a preview

Comment: You never assign anything to Z, so it is an empty string (nil), and after `Split` you take the second item (index `[1]`) from the resulting empty list. That is bound to go wrong.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis I changed the order by assigning a value to the variable and changing the index to 0 but it returns only the values of memo2

Comment: Well, you do: `Z := Memo2.Lines[J];`, so it is obvious it only finds strings in that memo.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

solved

```
var
I, J : byte;
begin
  for I := 0 to Memo1.Lines.Count -1 do
  begin
    for J := 0 to Memo2.Lines.Count -1 do
    begin
      if Pos(Split(Memo2.Lines[J], ',')[0],Memo1.Lines[I]) > 0 then
        Memo3.Lines.Add(Memo1.Lines[I]+' # '+Memo2.Lines[J]);
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Rather use `Integer` than `Byte`: if `Lines.Count` is `0`, then `Count - 1` is negative. By using `Byte` as local variable, you don't save any memory anyway. Always prefer to use `Integer`for such situations.

Comment: FWIW, you don't test if the result of Split isn't empty. Don't try to produce complicated one-liners (as in your question: the J loop is terribly wrong). Make everything as clear as possible and use variables where necessary.

Comment: Indeed, `Proper Code` > `Short Code`