# Parsing a string using a delimiter to a TStringList, seems to also parse on spaces (Delphi)

Tags: delphi, parsing, tstringlist

I have a simple string which is delimited by some character, let's say a comma.  I should be able to create a TStringList and set it's delimiter to a comma then set the DelimitedText to the text I want to parse and it should be automaticlly parsed.

The problem is when I look at the output it also includes spaces as delimiters and chops up my results.  How can I avoid this, or is there a better way to do this.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

There's a StrictDelimiter property on the TStringList.  Set it to True and it will only parse on the delimiter, not the spaces.

Comment: Note: This is only available from Delphi 2005 (or 2006) only. If you are using an older version, you can create your own subclass of TStringList with a "StrictDelimitedText" property. Unfortunately SetDelimitedText is both private and non-virtual (in D7 at least) so you can't override it.

Answer (score 5):

That's standard, documented behavior of the [`TStrings.DelimitedText`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/Classes.TStrings.DelimitedText) property. You want to set the [`StrictDelimiter`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/Classes.TStrings.StrictDelimiter) property to *true* to disable that behavior.

Answer (score 5):

You can have a look on the function "ExtractStrings" , if you are using d7